# Quais as diferenças entre o RMarkdown e o RNotebook?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

O `RMarkdown` se tornou uma interface e um tipo de arquivo muito popular nos últimos anos. Acredito que isso se deve ao fato de ele permitir utilizar um único software para escrever relatórios completos de análises estatísticas, com textos, tabelas, gráficos, figuras e referências formatadas. Também permite a compilação desses relatórios em de páginas html na internet. Depois que aprendemos a utilizá-lo, não é preciso mais ficar alternando entre janelas do R/Stata/Sas/SPSS e o Word, Excel, Latex, etc. Há até mesmo pacotes para ajudar a se escrever livros e teses de doutorado com ele. Obviamente, há também limitações e dificuldades (ao menos para mim) mas que fogem ao escopo da pergunta.

Recentemente, reparei que quando escolhemos a opção de criar um novo documento de RNotebook, um documento do RMarkdown também é aberto. A única diferença que parece existir é no YAML, onde há o parâmetro:

```
output: html_notebook
```

Quando esse parâmetro é mantido, o botão `knit` se converte num botão `preview`, que permite a visualização prévia do documento como página `html`. Mas depois que terminamos o trabalho e escolhemos compilar o documento (mesmo como html), o parâmetro do YAML é automaticamente mudado para:

```
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
```

O botão `preview` também desaparece e em seu lugar, volta a opção `knit`. Quando salvamos o arquivo, o R salva com a mesma extensão do Rmarkdown.

Ou seja, parece não haver nenhuma diferença mais entre os dois tipos de documento. É isso mesmo? Há alguma diferença objetiva e substantiva entre o RMarkdown e o RNotebook? Em caso afirmativo, poderiam me dar exemplos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RNotebook usa R Markdown, que é uma extensão da linguagem de marcação Markdown com suporte para embutir blocos de código R. Ou seja, em qualquer caso, é o mesmo formato de arquivo, com a mesma sintaxe (pode inclusive escrever o arquivo em qualquer aplicativo de texto, assim como qualquer código R ou markdown). A diferença está na execução do código. O Knit cria um ambiente próprio e todo o código é executado de uma vez, o R Notebook usa o ambiente global e roda uma linha de cada vez.

Quando abre/cria um arquivo R Markdown usando R Notebook, o markdown é convertido em HTML para gerar o *preview*, mas nenhum código R é executado a princípio. À medida que executa blocos de código R e/ou salva o arquivo, o *preview* é atualizado. Para compilar, o código completo é executado em um ambiente limpo, para que apenas objetos e valores definidos nos blocos de código façam parte do documento final (por isso o Preview some e aparece o Knit).